# Command for generating bundle installer not working

Tags: orocommerce

While following the Oro documentation for generating an installer for my bundle
I get the following error when using the `oro:migration:dump --bundle=MyBundle` command:

> In schema-template.php.twig line 38:
> Unexpected token "name" of value "table" ("end of statement block"
> expected).

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?